# AngularJS ui-router unable to load templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I have this kind of project structure:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ui-view=""></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**bread.html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
This is the bread view.
  <div ui-view="filters"></div>
  <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
  <div ui-view="graph"></div>
</div>
```

**bread.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('bread', {
    url: '/bread',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/breadcrumbs/views/home.tpl.html',
      },
      'filters@bread': {
        templateUrl: 'app/breadcrumbs/views/home1.tpl.html',
      },
    },
    controller: 'BreadCtrl'
  });
 });
```

The html files being loaded as templates are pretty simple. Just contain paragraph tags.

I have tried using nested views, but in the **ui-view="filters"** I am unable to load the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should put you `bread.html` in the base view of your state, and then load `named-view` from the views, `@` stands for the base layout template here

```
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('bread', {
    url: '/bread',
    views: {
      '@': {
        //I don't know the exact bread.html url, it can be different
        templateUrl: 'bread.html', //base layout which will make named-view available
      },
      'filters@bread': {
        templateUrl: 'app/breadcrumbs/views/home1.tpl.html',
      },
      'tabledata@bread': {
        templateUrl: 'app/breadcrumbs/views/tabledata.tpl.html',
      },
      'graph@bread': {
        templateUrl: 'app/breadcrumbs/views/tabledata.tpl.html',
      },
    },
    controller: 'BreadCtrl'
  });
});
```

Comment: @swateek Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: One more question, was it because I wasn't loading all the ui-views my page was coming blank?

Comment: Uh..oh! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @swateek Cool..Cheers..Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use named views you must to specify name with `ui-view` directive. OR just place it as 'clean' directive without value: `<div ui-view></div>`

If you want to use nested view you need to create parent view and child view. In this case you firstly load your parent view inside main `ui-view` directive and then you load child view inside your parent view. So your parent view must also contain `ui-view` directive inside. In this case your states should be smth like this:

`.state("parent", {
    url: "/parentSegment",
    templateUrl: "path to parent view"
})
.state("parent.child", {
    url: "/childSegment",
    templateUrl: "path to your child view"
})`

The resulting url in this case will be `protocol://host/parentSegment/childSegment`

You can skip child segment in url just leaving url parameter empty for child:

`.state("parent.child", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "path to your child view"
})`

In this case you'll have `protocol://host/parentSegment`

As you can see, nested views are have 'prefix' in their names the same as the parent view name and child part of name is appended to it with dot (.)

For information about nested view refer to [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) link, and for more info about named view you should visit [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) link

Comment: Thank you Andrew, but there are other dependencies on the base index.html, so am not sure if I can move it from empty string to no-name.

Comment: this are only examples. specify url for child state or leave it empty - your choice) its not of the thing that you must/need/have to have in your app